# Избежание продублированного кода в конструкторах класса. С++

Tags: c++

```
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo()
    {
        Сделать X
    }
    Boo(int value)
    {
        Сделать Х
        СделатЬ У
    }
};
```

Например мне нужно сделать что-то в конструкторах. Причем в этих двух конструкторах есть продублированный код. Насколько я знаю, есть два способа это избежать

```
// 1 вариант
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo()
    {
        Сделать X
    }
    Boo(int value):Boo()
    {
        СделатЬ У
    }
};
```

```
// 2 Вариант

class Boo
{
public:
    Boo()
    {
        doX();
    }
    Boo(int value)
    {
        doX();
        Сделать У;
    }

    void doX()
    {
        Делает X;
    }
};
```

Какой из них лучше ? Почему ? Или может есть получше ?

Comment: Лучше в каком плане? В плане производительности  лучше первый вариант...

Comment: Да, наверное, в плане производительности. А почему?

Comment: Вариант 3: 1 конструктор `Boo():Boo({}){}`, второй без изменений

Comment: А в таком абстрактном примере нет никакого критерия, позволившего бы выбрать тот или иной вариант.

Comment: Ну хоть бы private doX сделал...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше_ это понятие относительное. Лучше, когда все соответствует вашим пожеланиям и пожеланиям и удобствам пользователей. Если пользователью может понадобится  метод  `void doX()`, то лучше второй вариант, потому что в первом нет этого метода, а если нет, то лучше первый вариант, поскольку в первом меньше вызовов функций.  Конечно, в основном бывает полезнее вариант такой:

```
  class Boo
{
public:   
    Boo(int value = 0)
    {
        Сделать X
        if (value )
           СделатЬ У
    }
};
```

Поскольку тут нет лишных вызовов(лучше в плане производительности) и меньше кода (лучше для читабельности и  наверное компиляции). Тут разницы такие мизерные, что можно говорить в принципе только о читабельноси... Т.е. по возможности меньшим кодом нужно добится желаемого результата.

### Обновление:

Еще раз говорю, все зависит от ваших намерений, потому что однозначно говорить как нужно, невозможно. Например если у меня есть такие тривиальные определения:

```
void B()
{
    std::cout << "I am Boo\n";
}
void foo(int n)
{
    std::cout << "i created with  " << --n << '\n';
}

class Boo
{
public:
    Boo(int value)
    {
       B();
       foo(value);
    }
    Boo()
    {
        B();
    }
};
class His_variant {
public:
    His_variant(int value)
    {  
       B();  
       foo(value);
    }
    //разве это то, что я хотел выразить?...
    His_variant() : His_variant(0) {}       
};
class My_version {
public:
    My_version(int value = 0)
    {
        B();
        if (value)
            foo(value);
    }
};
```

То, если мы напишем программу:

```
// первый вариант
Boo b, bb(22);
std::cout <<"\n----------------" << std::endl;

// вариант с другого ответа
His_variant h, hh(22);
std::cout <<"\n----------------" << std::endl;

// вариант, о котором говорил я
My_version m, mm(22);
```

Первыи и третий вариант выдадут одинаковый результат, с той разницей, о чем я говорил, а вариант второй(о чем говорилось в другом ответе), естественно, выдаст совершенно другой результат

Comment: В общем случае не будет работать, например, если при *любом значении value* нужно `Сделать Y`, а иногда требуется *только* `Сделать X`

Comment: @avp, я не разбираю все случаи жизни, а отвечаю на конкретный вопрос конкретного человека, а по вопросу  можно легко догадаться, что тут не вами указанный общий случай, а случай конкретный.  К тому же я указал, что "Лучше, когда все соответствует вашим пожеланиям и пожеланиям и удобствам пользователей "

Comment: А я как раз из примеров его кода (варанты 1 и 2 в тексте вопроса) вижу, что формально ваш ответ не подходит. Не знаю, почему он его принял.

Comment: Зря. Тут же совершенно формальная логика. В обоих вариантах ТС выполняет `СделатЬ У` при *любом значении value*

Comment: @avp,  не хочу обсуждать ваше заблуждение. Разговор окончен

Comment: @avp В моем случае как раз таки, если пользователь не задал 'value' , тогда не делаем Y, что  в принципе и происходит у ARHovsepyan. Согласен, если бы были такие условия как у вас, тогда бы думаю и ARHovsepyan не дал бы такого ответа.

Comment: Я дополню ответ, для ясности

Answer (score 7):

Если "действия", о которых вы говорите, должны производиться именно *в теле* конструктора (между `{}`), то никакой принципиальной разницы между этими подходами нет. Второй вариант лишь заводит лишнюю сущность - дополнительный метод класса. Если закрыть на это глаза, то без разницы как делать.

Но тут надо заметить, что в конструкторе в первую очередь нас интересует устранение повторений *в списке инициализации*, т.е. именно для

```
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo(x, y) : 
        хитро_инициализировать_A(x, y), 
        хитро_инициализировать_B(x, y)
      {}
    Boo() : 
        хитро_инициализировать_A(3, 42),  
        хитро_инициализировать_B(3, 42)
      {}
};
```

Раньше нам приходилось извращаться через

```
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo(x, y) :
      // "Ложная" инициализация, возможно неявная
      инициализировать_A_какой-то-хренью, 
      инициализировать_B_какой-то-хренью
    { 
      do(x, y);
    }

    Boo() : 
      // "Ложная" инициализация, возможно неявная
      инициализировать_A_какой-то-хренью, 
      инициализировать_B_какой-то-хренью
    {
      do(3, 42);
    }

    void do(x, y)
    { // Вторая, "настоящая" инициализация 
      хитро_переинициализировать_A_по-новому(x, y);
      хитро_переинициализировать_B_по-новому(x, y);
    }
};
```

Т.е. в этом варианте `A` и `B` в общем случае сначала пройдут через некую инициализацию "по умолчанию", а затем - через дополнительную "доинициализацию" (или "переинициализацию") уже в функции. Это нерационально. Это неприятное явление известно как *проблема двойной инициализации*. И к тому же этот подход вообще невозможно никак применить для полей, не допускающих инициализацию по умолчанию или переинициализацию (поля-ссылки, константные поля и т.п.)

Вот тут-то нам и приходит на помощь

```
     ...
     Boo() : Boo(3, 42)
      {}
     ...
```

Этот вариант был введен в язык "относительно недавно" в первую очередь для того, чтобы решить вышеописанную проблему двойной инициализации. Подход с делегирующим вызовом конструктора свободен от этого недостатка. Выполняется именно инициализация и выполняется она ровно один раз.

Comment: Никакой речи и не было об инициализации в теле конструктора по умолчанию. Конструктор может выполнить тривиальный вывод сообщения, или что то еще подобное, абсолютно не требующие какие то значения...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, конструкторы, выводящие значения, нужны либо для отладки, либо в демонстрашках порядка запуска.

Comment: @Qwertiy,   в пользовательских классах, особенно в тестовых, в цельях эксперимента и изучения, в конструкторах можно делать ве что угодно...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, про что я и сказал ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я подтвердил...